# Best practices for loading up parameters under different modes into Python?

Tags: python, parameters, architecture, parameter-passing

So I have a python class, and it can engage in different "modes". In say, mode1, I have a hierarchy of different parameters and settings. In mode2, I have yet a different hierarchy of settings, etc. What is the best practice for how I load up those parameters?

Here is an example of what I mean: I have a python class named "Move", however movement can have different modes. If the mode is set to "walk", then the parameters it should load might be something like `coolness_factor = 11, right_foot_first = True`, etc. If however the mode is "fly", then maybe the parameters now are `coolness_factor = 43, wing_flap_rate = 2.1, wing_length = 4.5`, etc. I want to load all this in the **init** of my class of course.

So, what are the best practices for how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do..

```
class Move(object):
    def __init__(self, mode): 
        # I declared variables here for better view, you can remove it
        self.coolness_fac = 0
        self.right_foot_first = 0
        self.wing_flap_rate = 0
        self.wing_length = 0
        self.mode = mode
        if self.mode == "move":
            self.coolness_fac = 11
            self.right_foot_first = True

        if self.mode == "fly":
            self.coolness_fac = 43
            self.wing_flap_rate = 2.1
            self.wing_length = 4.5

    def printOut(self):
        print(self.mode)
        print(self.coolness_fac, 
        self.right_foot_first,
        self.wing_flap_rate,
        self.wing_length)

m = Move("fly") # or "move"
m.printOut()
```

This probably isn't the best practice but it should do the job.

The output of the code should be if `mode = "move"`

```
move
11 True 0 0
```

else if `mode = "fly"`

```
fly
43 0 2.1 4.5
```

good luck!